# Loading a variable automatically

Tags: php, laravel-4

laravel 4 application with many forms,

In the below example, how to make function `validate` load the `$register` rules if the value of `$form` is `register`

```
class Validation  {



private $register = array(

        "nick" => "required|min:2",
        "name" => "required|min:2",
        "surname" => "required|min:2",
        "day" => "required",
        "month" => "required",
        "year" => "required",
        "country" => "required",
        "address" => "required",
        "city" => "required",
        "postalCode" => "required",
        "email"     => "Required|Between:3,64|Email",
        'password'  =>'Required|AlphaNum|Between:6,32|Confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'Required|AlphaNum',
        "currency" => "required",
        "language" => "required"

);

private $support = array(

         "text"=>"required",
         "subject"=>"required"

);



public static function validate($input,$form) {

    return Validator::make($input, $form);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer myself - use variables variables

http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php

```
public static function validate($input,$form) {



        return Validator::make($input,self::$$form);

}
```